# Randomizing the locations

Tags: c#, multithreading

guys, last time's code now works, but there is something else; this time, I need the image to appear randomly in different areas than in multiple areas (get what I mean?)

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace War_Game
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Thread th;
        Thread th1;
        Random rdm;

        private void ally_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            th = new Thread(sand);
            th.Start();
        }

        public void sand()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                /* this.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 4), new Rectangle(rdm.Next(0, this.Height), rdm.Next(0, this.Width), 20, 20)); */
                this.CreateGraphics().DrawImage(new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\x\Downloads\sandler.png"), new Rectangle(rdm.Next(0, this.Height), rdm.Next(0, this.Width), 30, 30));
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Adam Sandler has invaded your program!");
        }

        private void foe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            th1 = new Thread(cage);
            th1.Start();
        }

        public void cage()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                /* this.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 4), new Rectangle(rdm.Next(0, this.Height), rdm.Next(0, this.Width), 20, 20)); */
                this.CreateGraphics().DrawImage(new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\x\Downloads\nicolas.png"), new Rectangle(rdm.Next(0, this.Height), rdm.Next(0, this.Width), 30, 30));
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Nicolas Cage has invaded your program!");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rdm = new Random();
        }
    }
}
```

This code makes the face appear in many areas, but I want one face to go in many places. With a code like this, how would you have the image change locations randomly?

Comment: What do you mean, 'one face to go in many places'?

Comment: Do you mean that the image is duplicated in all of the places, but you need it to disappear from a previous location before appearing in a new location?

Comment: Yeah, only one face must be there, but for each new location, that face from the old location disappears. Think of it like "appear and disappear".

Comment: FYI, rather than having different methods that have the exact same code except for a file path and a message string, it would be better to have a single method that takes a file path and a message as a arguments. This reduces the amount of duplicated code, and makes it easier to modify since there's only one method to update when making a change.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `Invalidate` method to force the form to redraw itself, which will remove the previously drawn image from the `CreateGraphics` call:

```
public void sand()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        CreateGraphics().DrawImage(new Bitmap(@"c:\temp\sandler.jpg"), 
            new Rectangle(rdm.Next(0, Height), rdm.Next(0, Width), 30, 30));
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        // Force the form to redraw and remove the image
        Invalidate();
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Adam Sandler has invaded your program!");
}
```

---

Also, rather than having different methods that have the exact same code except for a file path and a message string, it would be better to have a single method that takes a file path and a message as a arguments. This reduces the amount of duplicated code, and makes it easier to modify since there's only one method to update when making a change.

This can be done easily if we use a `Task` instead of a `Thread`:

```
private void ally_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SpawnImage(@"c:\temp\sandler.jpg", "Adam Sandler"));
}

private void foe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SpawnImage(@"c:\temp\cage.jpg", "Nicolas Cage"));
}

public void SpawnImage(string imagePath, string name)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        CreateGraphics().DrawImage(new Bitmap(imagePath), 
            new Rectangle(rdm.Next(0, Height), rdm.Next(0, Width), 30, 30));
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Invalidate();
    }

    MessageBox.Show($"{name} has invaded your program!");
}
```

---

Or maybe even better, you can show the message box *after* starting the task instead of inside the method that the task starts. This way the message box pops up while the image is flashing all over the form, rather than after it's all done:

```
private const string SandlerPath = @"c:\temp\sandler.jpg";
private const string CagePath = @"c:\temp\cage.jpg";

private void ally_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SpawnImage(SandlerPath));
    MessageBox.Show("Adam Sandler has invaded your program!");
}

private void foe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SpawnImage(CagePath));
    MessageBox.Show("Nicholas Cage has invaded your program!");
}

public void SpawnImage(string imagePath)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        CreateGraphics().DrawImage(new Bitmap(imagePath), 
            new Rectangle(rdm.Next(0, Height), rdm.Next(0, Width), 30, 30));
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```